# How to create a mail client with iPhone texting style view?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, messaging

I would like to create a messaging service on my app which would look like the texting interface on the iPhone. The mail client would be used with Google Mail, so I would need to get the username and password from `UITextFields`.

Could this be done with the Google API and with the texting/messaging style interface?

Thank you,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This video tutorial](http://vimeo.com/8718829) (or [this one that subclasses UITableViewCell](http://vimeo.com/22841414)) shows a pretty simple way of creating an SMS-style user interface; they even give you a link to the Xcode project from the tutorial video and a zip file with the images you would need to pull this off. This is done by customizing the cells of a UITableView to get the message data to display in the correct style.

Comment: I've followed that tutorial and now have the interface where it sends and loads the text. How can I then integrate mailing with this interface? Thanks!

Comment: I would look into using [the MFMailComposeViewController class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) that @AndrewWilcox mentioned in his answer.

Comment: but this would pull up a view controller? I need it to do the mailing silently in the background...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you there. I would encourage you to post a new question to get this answer as I'm sure there are others out that can readily answer this one for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the mail account already on the device and use [the MFMailComposeViewController class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) to send the message.  This would provide you a native Apple-style message interface and also be future-proof, in case the message interface changes in a later revision of iOS.

Comment: yes, but I ideally wanted the texting interface - as seen here: http://www.cultofmac.com/att-eliminating-10-texting-plans-for-all-new-iphone-customers/

Answer (score 1):

Google's Gmail API's will get you SMTP/IMAP access, but that's about it. It won't make sending and receiving email especially easy.
http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/

If you're interested in integrating Google services into your iOS apps take a look at Google's  drop-in OAuth implementation: 
http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/

Your idea is *possible*, but it won't be easy and Apple generally rejects third-party email clients. Good luck